# Ionic 2, Dynamically adding listeners to Markers in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, google-maps-markers, listeners

I am able to create all of my pins and add listeners to them but the first one created never gets a listener... I'm totally stumped by this. Any help would be awesome. Here is my code.

```
AddMarkers(lat, lng, name, num){
  /* Create the markers */
  let positionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng,),
    title: name,
    num: num,
  });
  /* Add listeners */
  positionMarker.addListener('click', () => {
    console.log("clicked" + positionMarker.title);
  });
  this.allMarkers.push({
    pm: positionMarker,
  });
  if(num == 0){
    this.AdjustMap(lat, lng);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I'm leaving this to help beginning coders.

I was doing everything correct but my issue was when I called "AdjustMap()" I was creating an empty pin over the top of my new pins. This was not visible but was a remnant from some old code while I was developing.

```
AdjustMap(lat, lng){
let positionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: this.map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(
    lat,
    lng,
  ),
  title: "Current Position"
});
this.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
  lat,
  lng,
));
```

}

Which should read:

```
AdjustMap(lat, lng){
  this.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
    lat,
    lng,
  ));
}
```